# Angularjs with JQuery Shapeshift plugin issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using shapeshift jquery plugin to show items to allow the user to re arrange the items as they wish. I am listening on drop event to persist the reordering info to the backend and updating scope locally. As soon as I 
I updated the socpe and call scope.apply. The elements are messed up.

e.g if I have Items in the following order A, B, C and now the user rearranges them into B, C, A But, it immediately turns into B, A, C.

Shapeshift positions the elements using inline styles, I see the in line style values are reset by Angular wrongly.

Similar approach has been done by angular-ui sortable directive which uses JQuery sortable plugin. But, it doesn't use inline style and it works fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Any update is much appreciated.